# How to compute record count in Visual FoxPro Table using Header Bytes?

Tags: visual-foxpro, dbf

We have a table that gets corrupted from time to time with a "Not a table" error. Running the demo version of DBF Doctor, it reports the header has an incorrect record count.

Looking at the one example I could find, I'm not really sure how to figure out how to compute the record count using base 256.

Bytes 4-7 have the number of records in the DBF.

(https://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html)

The first 10 bytes from the DBF header I read using a small Java program are:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 20
2 -> 3
3 -> 31
4 -> 81
5 -> 113
6 -> 0
7 -> 0
8 -> 0
9 -> 0
10-> 0
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to compute the number of records in the DBF?

Want to see if I can write a quick utility to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you actually have VFP to work with?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the rows by multiplying by 256. For each byte (from least to most significant), you have to multiply the value of that byte by (256^n).

For your example:

```
81 = 81
113 * 256 = 28928
0 * 256 * 256 = 0
0 * 256 * 256 * 256 = 0

81 + 28928 + 0 + 0 = 29009
```

The calculation is also discussed in [this thread](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=551810), but it's FoxPro Code.

A better understanding of this topic can be achieved by looking at your dbf with a [Hex-Editor](https://hexed.it/).

Comment: Thanks very much. I was using iHex also.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have VFP available,

[VFP Code to fix file headers](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~UDFFixRecCount) is available and done directly in VFP.  Relatively simple procedure and computes the file header record counts fix and adjusts via low-level file open/write operation.  I have used on more than once in the past.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to get the record count in the DBF header, but the current challenge is being able to loop through the DBF and get the actual record count to match what's in the header (so I have a programmatic way to update the header). In some cases, the looping code matches exactly the header value, but in other cases it doesn't. Note, your link above gives a "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." error, but I found this code anyway.

Comment: Sometimes the VFP code agrees with the header for the record count using its independent calculuation, other times, it doesn't. No idea why the record count doesn't match the header (and the DBF is OK) or how to fix that.